# Relative pronouns and Like doing or Like to do?

Tags: grammar

Hi everyone :) Please help me figure out these two questions below. I'm quite confused about them.

> **1.** Choose the best answer:
>
> The princess was happy during the years **_** she lived with the fairy.
>
> A. when
>   B. in which
>   C. where
>   D. that

I think A is the best choice but the key answer is D. I don't know why because I think in this situation "when" acts as an relative pronoun to express the period of time "she lived with the fairy" that made her happy.

> **2.** Choose the one that has the most similar meaning with the initial sentence
>
> I don't like anyone to tell me what to do.
>
> A. I don't like being tell what to do.
>   B. I don't like being told what to do,
>   C. I don't like to be told what to do.
>   D. I don't like to tell what to do.

This one, I think both B and C are correct but the key answer is B. 
So what is the differences here?

Thank you for your help. I'd highly appreciate that. =)

Comment: I think the makers of the test are using some grammatical rules that the rest of us have never heard of … if you want to get a high score on this test, you will have to figure out what these rules are.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, Lucas. Thanks for the details in your question, and the reasons supporting your choices. It will help in the responses you get.

Comment: [Here](http://d.violet.vn/uploads/resources/499/2128678/preview.swf) is a test with the some of the same questions but different answers. However, I wouldn't trust the answers given in that link; two of them are incorrect.

Comment: Approximately the same here [http://diendanngoaingu.vn/archive/index.php/t-30933.html?s=37642cff3301f20a3824eee14cb94e41]. But note the introduction of a "," after the years.

Comment: _That_ can be used instead of any _Wh_-pronoun in any restrictive relative clause, and is required instead of _how_, which cannot occur alone as a relative pronoun. E.g, _I like the way that he does it_ ~ _*I like the way how he does it._

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better asked on ell.se

Answer (score 2):

[**When**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/when): (adverb) at or during the time that; during which time; [adverb](http://www.yourdictionary.com/when): describes a point in time, and the circumstances under which something occurred.

[in which](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/when): (relative pronoun) used for adding information or a comment about a particular thing or fact when it is already clear what that thing or fact is

[**where**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/where) (adverb) at or in what place

[that](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/that?show=0&t=1388899022) (pronoun)  the time, action, or event specified; *after that I went to bed*

The only explanation I have for the correct answer is that it should be an adverb, as it modifies "she lived"; the two choices are *when* and *where*, so the obvious choice is **when**.

Example 2:

most similar to: *I don't like* **anyone to tell me** *what to do.* has to + infinitive

A. I don't like **being tell** what to do. wrong.
B. I don't like **being told** what to do. Same tense, present
C. I don't like **to be told** what to do. infinitive *to be*, otherwise exactly the same as B.
D. I don't like **to tell** what to do. wrong.
I think B and C are correct, with C having the advantage of having the infinitive form.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me :-) I highly appreciate that.

Comment: Yes, but I think whoever set these questions is in the wrong job. Personally, I'd say the best answer to #1 would normally be "none of the above" (specifically, *no intervening word is necessary*).

Comment: Googling, I think I can figure out where the person who set these  questions got his inspiration. There's a question on another ESL test which asks part of the sentence *"I don't like being tell what to do"*  is wrong. The answer (multiple choice) is that *tell* is incorrect. So the person who set the test included the original incorrect sentence: A, the corrected sentence in the answer key: B, and two plausible-sounding alternatives. Unfortunately, one of the plausible-sounding alternatives also happened to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, I think what they imagine that they are testing is your ability to use *relative clauses* based one of the links with the same question. That being said,  I find all four versions comprehensible as an AmE native speaker and know no rule prohibiting any of them.

Guessing as to why they don't, I can come up with rules to give you their answer if I look at the sentence as follows:

> The princess was happy during the years

This sentence is inadequate because *years* is too ambiguous to mean anything. Thus they want the next clause to modify years.

*that* will make a relative clause which modifies *years*. i.e., The princess was happy during **the years that she lived with the fairy**

I think they imagine *when* will modify the sentence as a whole, i.e. was happy ... **when she lived with the fairy** which would leave *during the years* ambiguous. I think this is wrong as a way of understanding the clause but I can see why they would mistakenly think this.

I don't see why they think *in which* on this basis.
For *where*, they probably think it cannot be applied to times.

---

For your second question, *being told what to do* and *to be told what to do* have the same exact same meaning to me and merely reflect two different ways of expressing this (the former pattern being the Norman-French pattern and the latter the Teutonic-Saxon [German]).

Other thoughts?